# Is there a way to display ASCII symbols in java?

Tags: java, byte, ascii, symbols, pcap

I am viewing a capture textfile and it shows the symbols that are obtained from the hexadecimal value in ASCII. In Notepad++ it also shows the symbols from `00 to 1F` the are nicely mapped out by [this webpage](http://www.december.com/html/spec/ascii.html) and you can find the full ASCII table including the extended values with their hexadecimal and decimal numbers [here](http://www.ascii-code.com/). I understand that they are meant to be control characters but is there any way to show them in java?

Here is what is a sample of what is shown in the file
[image]

I can get all the the other ASCII symbols to show in my java program, but not the ones with the symbols like `STX NUL EOT SOH` etc.. which are the values from `0 to 31` in decimal, and `00 to 1F` in hex.

Here is a snapshot of ASCII table from [here](http://www.ascii-code.com/)
[image]

Here is a console snippet of what is shown in the console
[image]

This is the code i'm using to print that out.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
int length = (int) new File(filePath).length();
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
fis.read(buffer, 0, length);

for (int i = 1; i < hex.length(); i++){
                if(i %2 == 0){
                    String test = String.valueOf(hex.charAt(i-2))+ String.valueOf(hex.charAt(i-1));

                    System.out.println("Hex: "+test+" hexadecimal: "+Integer.parseInt(test, 16)+" char: "+(char) Integer.parseInt(test, 16));
                }
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What is `hex`?  It’s not declared in the (incomplete) code you’ve provided.  It appears you are converting your bytes to a String of hex digits, and then parsing them back into integral values;  there is, as far as I can tell, no reason for this round-trip process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are displaying the value as a char, so it will be automatically interpreted by your console as a character with a specific way to be displayed.

If you want to display something which matches the Notepad view, you'd probably have to use a table for non printable characters, which would look like:

```
private static final String[] myTable = {"NUL", "SOH", ... };
public String getCharAsString(char value) {
    if(value <= (char) 0x1F) {
        return myTable[value];
    } else {
        return "" + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of this. Very simple and well explained solution.